# Installing Bootstrap 4 for Ruby on Rails on windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

Receiving an error (ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#home) when I run rails server and load my page after I install bootstrap 4 ruby gem.

Completely new to Ruby on rails and largely programming so bear with me. I'm running through the One month rails tutorial (https://onemonth.com/courses/rails/curriculum) and hitting a sticking point at the installing bootstrap 4 point. I'm using windows 10 vs Mac OS for the tutorial.

I've tried running through the same directions for installing bootstrap 4 as the course uses (https://www.diycode.cc/projects/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) as well as the latest directions (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem). I get the same error either way, but my latest attempt runs through the steps below.

Steps

Add **bootstrap** to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.2.1'
```

**bundle install**

Import Bootstrap styles in **app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss**:

```
// Custom bootstrap variables must be set or imported *before* bootstrap.
@import "bootstrap";
```

renamed application.css to application.scss in app/assets/stylesheets/

add the **jquery-rails** gem to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

**bundle install**

Add Bootstrap dependencies and Bootstrap to your **application.js**:

```
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

I've also tried removing

```
gem 'duktape'
```

from my gemfile as has been suggested elsewhere but had no luck.

**Gemfile**

```
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.3.3'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'duktape'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.2.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**application.scss**

```
// Custom bootstrap variables must be set or imported *before* bootstrap.
@import "bootstrap";
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>
<p>Sign up here</p>
<p>Teams</p>
<p>Standings</p>
<p>Schedules</p>
<p>Stats</p>
```

When I run rails server the page comes up saying "ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#home"

Showing C:/omrails/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #8 raised:

undefined not callable

Rails.root: C:/omrails

(execjs):1
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__882755417_31415124'

My code in views/layouts/application.html.erb looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>One Month Rails</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>    

  </head>

  <body>
    <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
    <%= link_to "About", about_path %>
    <%= link_to "Contact us", contact_path %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There may be an issue either in the controller for Pages#home or in the view itself.  Add that to the OP for people to see

Comment: did you installed are the rails dependencies like node js etc

Comment: I'm not sure about node js, not seeing "using node js "when I bundle install